# Setting up responsive dropdown nav with hamburger tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, nav

I'm an amateur at setting up a responsive nav and looking up tutorials online don't seem to direct me to the end result I want when I try it out. See screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

This is a rough idea how I want the nav to behave at a certain break point but I have no idea how to make this idea functional. Can someone help me set a base for this or direct me to a helpful tutorial with everything I need (js and css media query)? Thank you.

Comment: the problem you may encounter when you create the burger menu with a sub-nav to the side is the limited space you will get. You would be better to add the sub-nav below its parent nav item

Comment: Check this: http://www.cssscript.com/multi-level-toggle-responsive-navigation-menu-using-pure-css/

Comment: SO isn't a place to ask people to write code for you. Use what you've found in your research to try it yourself first and then post back here with specific problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

As a concept maybe use smt like this:

```css
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hamb {
  display: none;
}

label:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;  
}
.navi {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  
}
.navi > li {
  padding: 10px ;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 2px;
  border: none;
  }
.navi > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.navi li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .hamb {
  display: block;
  } 

  input + section {
 display: none
}
  input:checked + section {
 display: block
}
  .navi {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
     -webkit-box-align: end;
     -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
         -ms-flex-align: end;
             align-items: flex-end;
  }
  .navi > li {
    
  }
  .navi > li > ul {
      left: calc(-100% + 4px);
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="hamb" style="text-align: right"><label for="menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></label></div>

<input type="checkbox" id="menu">
<section>
<ul class="navi">
<li>Link 1
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1.1
      <li>Link 1.2
        <li>Link 1.3
          
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Link 2 
    <ul>
    <li>Link 2.1
      <li>Link 2.2
        <li>Link 2.3
          
  </ul>
    <li>Link 3
     <li>Link 4
      <li>Link 5
  
</ul>
<section>
```

**UPD** 
play with styles to make it work correct. I'll do the answer best later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial on developing several types of responsive menus depending on how crazy you want to get with them. http://responsivenavigation.net/index.html I hope this helps you out.

Here is another example as well

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

 var $menu = $('#menu'),
   $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
   $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');

 $menulink.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $menulink.toggleClass('active');
  $menu.toggleClass('active');
 });

 $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
 });

});
```

```css
.example-header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-link { display: none;}
.menu { 
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}
.menu ul { 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
 min-width: 10em;
 padding: 4px 0;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.menu ul li { padding: 0px; }
.menu > ul > li { display: inline-block; }
.menu ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #000; font-size: .9em; }
.menu ul li > a { height:58px; padding: 19px 12px; }
.menu ul ul { 
  display: none; 
  position: absolute; 
  top:100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }
.menu ul ul > li { position: relative; }
.menu ul ul > li a { padding: 5px 15px 5px 10px; height: auto; background-color: #f4f4f4; }
.menu ul ul > li a:hover { background-color: #42BBA3; color: #fff; }
.menu ul ul ul { position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0; }

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .example-header .container { width: 100%; }
  
  a.menu-link { display: block; color: #fff; background-color: #333; float: right; text-decoration: none; padding: 19px 10px;}
  .menu { clear: both; min-width: inherit; float: none; }
  .menu, .menu > ul ul { overflow: hidden; max-height: 0; background-color: #f4f4f4; }
  .menu > li > ul.sub-menu { padding: 0px; border: none; }
  .menu.active, .menu > ul ul.active { max-height: 55em; }
  .menu ul { display: inline; }
  .menu > ul { border-top: 1px solid #808080; }
  .menu li, .menu > ul > li { display: block; }
  .menu li a { color: #000; display: block; padding: 0.8em; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080; position: relative; }
  .menu li.has-submenu > a:after {
    content: '+';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.55em 0.5em;
  }
  .menu li.has-submenu > a.active:after {
    content: "-";
  }
  .menu ul ul > li a { background-color: #e4e4e4; height:58px; padding: 19px 18px 19px 30px; }
  .menu ul ul, .menu ul ul ul { display: inherit; position: relative; left: auto; top:auto; border:none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="example-header cf">

 <div class="container">
  
  <a class="menu-link" href="#menu">Menu</a>
  
  <nav id="menu" class="menu">
   <ul>
          <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">For Facilities</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Field Maintenance</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">All-in-One Team Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Air &amp; Electrical Reels</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Field Drags</a></li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Field Marking Equipment</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Batter's Box Templates</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dryline Markers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Field Paint</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Field Sprayers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Stencils</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Field Tarps</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Area Tarps</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Growth Covers / Protectors</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Infield Tarps</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Tarp Accessories</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Hand Tools</a></li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Irrigation, Hoses, Nozzles</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Hoses &amp; Hose Reels</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Irrigation</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nozzles</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Layout &amp; Measurement Tools</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Moisture Removal</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Mound &amp; Home Plate Fortification</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Mowers &amp; Stripers</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Game-Practice Equipment</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Baseball - Softball</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Base Accessories</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bases &amp; Home Plates</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Game Accessories</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pitching Rubbers</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Batting Practice Equipment</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Backstops</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Infield Screens</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Jugs Pitching Machines</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Turf Mats</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Turf Protectors</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Replacement Accessories</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Portable Mounds</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Batting Practice Mounds</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Game Mounds</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Practice Mounds</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Football</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">First Down Markers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Football Accessories</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Football Goalposts</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="has-submenu">
             <a href="#">Soccer</a>
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Soccer Goals</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Soccer Accessories</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
             
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Training &amp; Conditioning</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Ladders &amp; Sticks</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Hurdles</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Training Accessories</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Smart-Cart Training System</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Books-Videos</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Field Design &amp; Maintenance</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>
  </nav>
 
 </div>

</header>
```